# How do I align text in "top right"?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have the following table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <b>Car Name:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad1%></div>
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad2%></div> 
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad3%></div>
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad4%></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The "Car Name:" column is right aligned, but in the center. Is there a way to align that column to the top right corner?

Comment: Just a side note concerning the XSS vulnerability that your site is exposed to by using `<%= Model.SomePropertyName %>`. So while you worry about aligning columns you have far bigger problems with your code.

Comment: If you use <%: %> it will HtmlEncode the content. So you probably want to use that in its place.

Comment: THanks for the help. Would <%: %> help in the cross site scripting vulnerability?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <b>Car Name:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad1%></div>
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad2%></div> 
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad3%></div>
            <div><%=Model.DataMayLoad4%></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use: `<td align="right" valign="top">`

Comment: deprecated.. Use PaulPRO's solution